# Switching Infinite and Finite Sums (Markov Chains and Mixing Times Theorem 20.3)

Tags: probability, solution-verification, proof-explanation, markov-chains

I was working through Theorem 20.3 Part (i) from  [Markov Chains and Mixing Times (Levin, Peres, Wilmer)](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf)  and I am confused about the justification of an inequality. From the book (p. 283):

> Proof of Theorem 20.3. (i), Step 1. Recall that $N_t$ is the Poisson random variable indicating the number of transitions in the continuous-time chain. We first prove
> $$
> \left\|H_t(x, \cdot)-\pi\right\|_{\mathrm{TV}} \leq \mathbf{P}\left\{N_t<k\right\}+\left\|P^k(x, \cdot)-\pi\right\|_{\mathrm{TV}} .
> $$
> Conditioning on the value of $N_t$ and **applying the triangle inequality** give
> $$
> \left\|H_t(x, \cdot)-\pi\right\|_{\mathrm{TV}} \leq \sum_{j \geq 0} \mathbf{P}\left\{N_t=j\right\}\left\|P^j(x, \cdot)-\pi\right\|_{\mathrm{TV}}
> $$

**My question:** I feel like I am missing something simple, **but why can one get the inequality from applying the triangle inequality alone?** My thought was that, because you have an infinite sum, you would need Fubini-Tonelli or something like this to exchange the sums?  The following is my attempt at a proof:

By definition (p.281), the Heat Kernel with transition matrix P is

$$
\begin{aligned}
H_t(x, y) & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-r t}(r t)^k}{k !} P^k(x, y)
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, using $P^k_x$ to denote the distribution at time $k$ starting from $x$, and $(H^t_x$ is analogous.)

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\|H^t_x - \pi\|_{TV}& =\left\| \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-r t}(r t)^k}{k !} P_x^k\right) - \pi\right\|_{TV}\\
&\leq\left|\sum\limits_{\omega \in A}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-r t}(r t)^k}{k !} P_x^k(\omega)\right) - \pi(\omega)\right|\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
$$

Using A to denote the set which maximizes the absolute value of the difference between $P_x^k$ and $\pi$ , then this line follows from the definition of TVD.

Then by Fubini-Tonelli

$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-r t}(r t)^k}{k !}
\sum\limits_{\omega \in A} P_x^k(\omega) - \pi(\omega)\right|
$$

Then by Triangle inequality

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left| \frac{e^{-r t}(r t)^k}{k !}
\sum\limits_{\omega \in A} P_x^k(\omega) - \pi(\omega)\right|\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left| \frac{e^{-r t}(r t)^k}{k !}\right|
\left|\sum\limits_{\omega \in A} P_x^k(\omega) - \pi(\omega)\right|\\
&\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-r t}(r t)^k}{k !}
\|P_x^k-\pi \|_{TV}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(N(rt)=k)
\|P_x^k-\pi \|_{TV}\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
$$

where N(rt) is a poisson of rate $rt$. And this is the same as the given inequality. Please do let me know if I've made a mistake in my proof. If not though, I'm not sure how you would get here without using something to interchange the sum from TVD and the infinite sum.

Comment: what is the function $H_t$?

Comment: @stochs $H_t$ is the heat kernel. It is defined on Page 281 of the reference I gave. The definition is also the first equation in the proof I gave.

Comment: I think the absolute value should be inside of $\sum_{\omega\in A}$ and not outside, which prevents you interchanging the integrals.

Comment: @gabalz Hmm but I was thinking if you use the definition $\|\mu-\nu\|_{\mathrm{TV}}=\max _{A \subseteq \mathcal{X}}|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|$, then you sum over all the atoms in A, it  be like $\|\mu-\nu\|_{\mathrm{TV}}=\max _{A \subseteq \mathcal{X}}|\sum_{\omega \in A}\left( \mu(\omega)-\nu(\omega)\right)|$ , no?

Comment: You are right, the problem is not there, you could have used Remark 4.3 as well.

Comment: @gabalz Yes very good point, and even more excellent points made in your follow up response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments your definition of $A$ wanted to be the maximizer event in the definition of $\|H_x^t-\pi\|_{TV}$, which can be written as $A = \{\omega\in\mathcal{X} : H_x^t(\omega) \ge \pi(\omega)\}$ by Remark 4.3 in [Markov Chains and Mixing Times (Levin, Peres, Wilmer)](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf).
Also, based on your observation, we have
$$
\left|\sum_{\omega \in A}P_x^k(\omega)-\pi(\omega)\right| \le \|P_x^k - \pi\|_{TV}
$$
by the definition of $\|\cdot\|_{TV}$ for any $A \subseteq \mathcal{X}$.

Hence it remains to prove that you can apply Fubini's theorem, which is true if:
$$
\sum_{\omega\in A}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-rt}(rt)^k}{k!} \left|P_x^k(\omega)-\pi(\omega)\right|
< \infty .
$$
But this holds by using $\sum_{\omega\in A}H_x^t(\omega) \le 1$ and $\sum_{\omega \in A}\pi(\omega) \le 1$ as they are distributions over the state space $\mathcal{X}$ and $A \subseteq \mathcal{X}$, and then
$$
\sum_{\omega\in A}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-rt}(rt)^k}{k!} \left|P_x^k(\omega)-\pi(\omega)\right|
\le \sum_{\omega\in A}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-rt}(rt)^k}{k!} \Big(P_x^k(\omega) + \pi(\omega)\Big)
= \sum_{\omega\in A} H_x^t(\omega) + \pi(\omega) \le 2 .
$$
So it seems that your proof is correct after all. Nice work! :)

Comment: Yes! Excellent catch! You're correct, that I really wanted to use the set $A = \{\omega\in\mathcal{X} : H_x^t(\omega) \ge \pi(\omega)\}$, and indeed there is probably not a single maximizer for $P^k_x$ and $\pi$. But maybe it is still ok? Because the total variation distance is the maximum over any A, so if I turn it into $ \left|\sum_{\omega \in A}P_x^k(\omega)-\pi(\omega)\right| \leq  \|P_x^k - \pi\|_{TV}$ and the proof should still go through I think?

Comment: Indeed, great observation, TVD takes the maximum, so it works! :) Then it remains to prove absolute convergence for the Fubini-theorem...

Comment: Ahh Perfect!! :) Thank you very much for taking the time to review my proof! I'm very glad to hear I was on the right track! :) Would you happen to have any intuition as to what the authors might have been doing at this step in the proof (what I quoted from my question)? They only claim to have used the triangle inequality, but I couldn't see how that is possible? Do you happen to notice a way that you can transition between the steps I quoted in my question, without using Fubini-tonelli?

Comment: I don’t see the triangle inequality either, but I think a simple proof follows from the convexity of TDV and Jensen’s inequality. I am without my laptop now, and I think you can figure it out, but if not, let me know, and I can write it down later…

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm glad to hear I'm not alone! I'm starting to think that details were just left out of this part of the proof in the textbook... I'll give your Jensen's 
idea a go! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this problem!!